How do I use a filter bank?
I need to create a filterbank file so I use this code:
import filterbank.header as header

header = {
    b'source_name': b'P: 80.0000 ms, DM: 200.000',
    b'machine_id': 10,
    b'telescope_id': 4,
    b'data_type': 1,
    b'fch1': 400,
    b'foff': -0.062,
    b'nchans': 128,
    b'tstart': 6000.0,
    b'tsamp': 8e-05,
    b'nifs': 1,
    b'nbits': 8
}

header.generate_file("file_path/file_name", header)

I replaced the file path with the file path that is specific to me but I keep getting the error "module not found".

It's unclear what library you are using exactly, can you provide a link to where the source or package can be found?
